# Mongoose collection is not getting updated

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update mongoose collection name `counter`.
But it's not getting updated.

**counter collection**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var counterSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {type: String, required: true},
    sequence_value: {type: Number, default: 1}
});

var Counter = module.exports = mongoose.model('Counter', counterSchema);
```

**API**

```
router.post('/increment',function(req, res, next){
console.log('Sequence Counter::' + getNextSequenceValue("productId"));
)};
```

**getNextSequenceValue Method**

```
function getNextSequenceValue(sequenceName){

   var sequenceDocument = Counters.findOneAndUpdate({
      query:{_id: sequenceName },
      update: {$inc:{sequence_value:1}},
      new:true,
      upsert: true
   });
  console.log('Counter value::' + sequenceDocument.sequence_value);
   return sequenceDocument.sequence_value;
}
```

But every time I hit `/increment` API, console.log is printing `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will always get `undefined` since `sequenceDocument` is a `Promise` which will later resolve with the updated document if the update operation is successful or will reject with an error if it is not. In your case the `console.log` statement will run before the database operation has completed. This is because `findOneAndUpdate` is an asynchronous operation which returns a `Promise` object.

The update probably fails because you are passing arguments to `findOneAndUpdate` in an improper manner. The function accepts the query as first argument, update operation as second and query options as third argument.

You can rewrite the `getNextSequenceValue` in the following way:

```
function getNextSequenceValue(sequenceName) {
  return Counters.findOneAndUpdate(
    { // query
      _id: sequenceName
    },
    { $inc: { sequence_value: 1 } }, // update operation
    { // update operation options
      new: true,
      upsert: true
    }
  ).then(sequenceDocument => sequenceDocument.sequence_value)
}
```

It will now return a `Promise` which will resolve with the sequence value. You can use it in your controller like this:

```
router.post('/increment', function(req, res, next) {
  getNextSequenceValue('productId')
    .then(sequenceValue => {
      console.log(sequenceValue)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // handle possible MongoDB errors here
      console.log(error)
    })
})
```

Comment: Getting `sequence_value is not defined`

Comment: IT's working fine, but I don't why my counter is getting updated by +2

Comment: I don't know as well. You might be hitting the route twice or something.

Comment: Hm, I am hitting only once. when I print `sequenceValue`, just for incrementation, then it's working fine. But when I add other logic inside it, then it's +2 increment.

Comment: I tried doing like this: `var productID;
  getNextSequenceValue('productId').then(sequenceValue => {
    productID = sequenceValue;
    //console.log(productID);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
    console.log(productID);`, but I am getting `undefined` why?

Comment: I think you have to read about how Promises work before continuing any further. You are basically making the same mistake.

Comment: I want to store `sequenceValue` in some variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163112/discussion-between-mayank-bisht-and-tsvetan-ganev).